# AngularJS Modal Singleton in Service Not Updating View

Tags: javascript, angularjs, angular-ui-bootstrap

I am trying to create a singleton 'LoadingDialog' service, but when closing an existing dialog, there is no update in the view.

ModalDialog service:

```
angular.module('app')
  .service('modalDialog', function ($modal) {
    this.create = function (templateUrl, data, size) {
      return $modal.open({
        templateUrl: templateUrl,
        controller: 'ModalDialogCtrl',
        size: size,
        backdrop: 'static',
        keyboard: false,
        resolve: {
          data: function () {
            return data;
          }
        }
      });
    };

    this.destroy = function (modalInstance) {
      modalInstance.close();
    };
  });
```

LoadingDialog service:

```
angular.module('app')
  .service('loadingDialog', function (modalDialog) {
    this.instance = null;

    this.show = function (text) {
      if (this.instance !== null) {
        this.hide();
      }
      this.instance = modalDialog.create('views/loading-dialog.html', {text: text});
    };

    this.hide = function () {
      modalDialog.destroy(this.instance);
    };
  });
```

You can see that I am storing the instance variable to ensure that only 1 loading dialog is shown at a time. This does not happen.

For example, in the Controller, the following code is executed:

```
loadingDialog.show('dialog 1');
loadingDialog.show('dialog 2');
loadingDialog.hide();
```

Now what I would expect, is for the first dialog to be created, then replaced by the second. When the hide method is invoked, there are no loading dialogs open.

Now what actually happens, is that the 2 dialogs are created on top of each other, and when the hide method is invoked, dialog2 is closed but dialog 1 is still open.

Only when the `loadingDialog` service's `hide` method is explicitly called from a controller does it seem to actually make a change to the view. If called from the service, nothing happens.

It seems to me that calling the `hide` method within the service itself is not updating the view, but I don't know how to fix this.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It looks like what you are doing is fine. Issue is with the delay that happens while opening the dialog by bootstrap. I uses a timeout inorder for the animation to happen, it then adds the dialog to track after animating. In your case you are trying to close it too early and in the modalstack close method it looks for opened windows and it is not there yet. It internally keeps a stack of opened windows in a factory [`$$stackedmap`](https://github.com/angular-ui/bootstrap/blob/f671e02e9712702b2f55947d9ead5783d991c439/src/modal/modal.js#L7) and it would not have had the window added in the stack yet.

*from [close method](https://github.com/angular-ui/bootstrap/blob/f671e02e9712702b2f55947d9ead5783d991c439/src/modal/modal.js#L285)*

```
 $modalStack.close = function (modalInstance, result) {
    var modalWindow = openedWindows.get(modalInstance); 
    if (modalWindow) {
      modalWindow.value.deferred.resolve(result);
      removeModalWindow(modalInstance);
    }
  };
```

In order to workaround you could use a timeout (with some interval near to the animation interval of 0.15s) wrapping the modalinstance.close.

```
this.destroy = function (modalInstance) {
 $timeout(function(){
    modalInstance.close();
  },150);
};
```

**[Demo](http://plnkr.co/edit/gzIe1Z?p=preview)**

Comment: This worked an absolute charm, thank you! How did you find out that the cause was due to an animation timeout?

Comment: @Cristian You are welcome. I did not do a thorough debugging but just a quick debugging figured.. :)